# JavaScript код не работает

Tags: javascript

При запуске кода программа не выводит результат. В консоли выдает ошибку `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"`

```js
function f1(n) {
  var prod = 1;
  while (n > 1) {
    prod *= n;
    n--;
  }
  return prod;
}

function f1(4);
```

Comment: Уберите слово `function` в `function f1(4)`;

Comment: @entithat Сперва у меня в конце кода  f1 не было, то есть так было function(4). Потом я исправила на function f1(4) чтоб проверить, подумала может сработает. Но выдал ошибку. Оба варианта не дают результат. И без function(ваш вариант) тоже написала но не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function f1(n) {
  var prod = 1;
  while (n > 1) {
    prod *= n;
    n--;
  }
  return prod;
}

var result = f1(4);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за правильный ответ. @Igor Но мне интересно почему тот код не работает, что там не правильно, потому что у меня часто такие ошибки возникают.

Comment: @Afina Там лишнее слово `function` перед `f1(4)`, и никуда не сохраняется результат вызова `f1`.

Comment: А все поняла, спасибо. Просто в книге вот так написано было: 

function f1(n) {
    var prod = 1;
    while (n > 1) {
        prod *= n;
        n--; }
    return prod;
}

 function (4) Наверно там не правильно, отпечатка может быть.

Comment: @Afina Очень хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.